# Get correct return value with abstract method inside function

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, abstract

I would like to check the result of an AsyncTask inside a method.

```
  private boolean isRequestSuccessfull(){
    boolean test = false;
    new HttpRequest() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(JSONObject result) {
            if (result.optBoolean("success")){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }.get(getBaseContext(), "myUrl");

    return test;
}
```

isRequestSuccessfull check if the result of the httpRequest is successfull.

HttpRequest is an AsyncTask who call the server and onResponseReceived is the abstract method who allow me to get the result of the request.

This code isn't working because I can't have a return boolean inside onResponseReceived.
I can't assigne the value test inside the onResonseReceived and return it, because the return will be executed before the assignement.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a `boolean` from your method make it `void` and let your anonymous `HttpRequest` do the method call when the response has been received e.g.

```
 new HttpRequest() {
     @Override
     public void onResponseReceived(JSONObject result) {
         if (result.optBoolean("success")) {
             callMethodWithBoolean(true);
         } else {
             callMethodWithBoolean(false);
         }
     }
 }.get(getBaseContext(), "myUrl");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't understand callMethodWithBoolean need to be declared inside HttpRequest ? What this method is supposed to do ?